# Can Galileo work with workspaces/projects created in Helios?

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

My desktop has `Helios` (3.6.1). My workspace and the projects under it were created using Helios.

My laptop has `Galileo` (3.5.2). I tried to open a copy of a project that was created through Helios and it opened fine.

But then, when I tried to change one of the Java Libraries via `Configure Build Path`, I received `Access Denied` error:

[image]

At first, I thought it was a Windows XP permissions problem, but after investigating this further, I ruled out this possibility. I have also been able to modify that `.classpath` file using Notepad, so clearly this isn't an ACL problem.

Therefore, I am now suspecting that there is an incompatibility problem between `Galileo` (3.5.2) and `Helios` (3.6.1).

Can you confirm this?

**If** there shouldn't be a compatibility issue between the two, what could I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: what does the "Details" section show/say?

Comment: @Saket See updated snapshot. Thanks.

Comment: ok, take a look at the answer posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I celebrated too early. While Saket's tip allowed getting rid of the build path error, numerous other problems emerged, which forced me to upgrade from 3.5.6 to 3.6.2.

I then discovered the following in [Eclipse's Release Notes](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/readme_eclipse_3.6.2.html#Upgrading):

> Note: Copying your workspace is recommended because, after you've
>   upgraded your workspace, **you won't be able to use it again with an
>   older version of Eclipse**. If you ever want to go "back in time" to
>   an earlier release, you will need that backup.

Therefore, the short answer to my question is simply: **No!**

Answer (score 2):

The solution at this post - http://blog.ryanrampersad.com/2010/03/03/setting-build-path-has-encountered-a-problem-in-eclipse - may help you!

Summary:

"The windows hidden attribute is set on the .classpath file. Removing this attribute fixes the error. After going into the workspace and project directory, remove the hidden attribute."

Comment: You were right on target! All I had to do is uncheck `Hidden` for that `.classpath` file and changing the build path via Eclipse work now! +1 +Accept.